# A conjecture about inclusion–exclusion

Tags: co.combinatorics, order-theory, lattice-theory, mobius-inversion

$\newcommand\calF{\mathcal{F}}
\def\cupdot {\stackrel{\bullet}{\cup}}
\def\minusdot {\stackrel{\bullet}{\setminus}}$This post presents a conjecture that we have with some colleagues. It is about reordering inclusion–exclusion to use only the intersections that do not cancel and the operations of disjoint union and subset complement. We are posting it here in case someone has an idea or know combinatorialists that might be interested (we are from TCS).

I write $[n] = \{1,\dotsc,n\}$. Let $\calF = \{S_1,\dotsc,S_n\}$ be a
finite family of pairwise incomparable (for inclusion) finite sets. For $T \subseteq
 [n]$, $T\neq \emptyset$, define $S_T = \bigcap_{j\in T} S_j$.
By [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) we have
$$\left\vert\bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i\right\vert =  \sum_{T\subseteq [n],T\neq \emptyset} (-1)^{|T|+1} |S_T|.$$

It can happen that $S_T = S_{T'}$ for $T \neq T'$, so that some of the
intersections disappear from the above sum. Call such an intersection *cancelling*,
the other intersections being *non-cancelling*.

**Example:**

Take $\calF = \{S_1,S_2,S_3\}$ with  $S_1=\{a,b,d\}$, $S_2=\{a,b,c,e\}$,
$S_3=\{a,c,f\}$. Then:
$$ \begin{align}
   |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3| ={} &|S_1| + |S_2| + |S_3| \\\\
                           & - (|S_1 \cap S_2| + |S_1 \cap S_3| + |S_2 \cap S_3|) \\\\
                           & + |S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3|.
 \end{align} $$

Since we have $S_1 \cap S_3 = S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
   |S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3| &= |\{a,b,d\}| + |\{a,b,c,e\}| + |\{a,c,f\}|- |\{a,b\}| - |\{a,c\}|.
 \end{align*}
The non-cancelling intersections are the ones that remain, i.e., $\{a,b,d\}$, $\{a,b,c,e\}$, $\{a,c,f\}$, $\{a,b\}$, and $\{a,c\}$, while
$\{a\}$ ($=S_1 \cap S_3 = S_1 \cap S_2 \cap S_3$) is a cancelling term.

The conjecture is that we can always express the union $\bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$ (not its size, but *the set itself*)
from the non-cancelling intersections, using only the operations of *disjoint
union* and *subset complement*. Formally, for two sets $A$, $B$ such that
$A\cap B = \emptyset$, define the *disjoint union* $A\cupdot B = A
 \cup B$. For two sets $A,B$ such that $B\subseteq A$, define the *subset
complement* $A\minusdot B = A \setminus B$.

**Conjecture:**
For any finite family of pairwise incomparable finite sets $\calF =
   \{S_1,\dotsc,S_n\}$, we can express $\bigcup_{i=1}^n S_i$ using only the
non-cancelling intersections and the operations of disjoint union and subset
complement.

**Example:**
Continuing the example, we can express~$S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3 =
   \{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$ with $ \bigl[\bigr((\{a,b,d\} \minusdot \{a,b\}) \cupdot
   \{a,b,c,e\}\bigr) \minusdot \{a,c\}\bigr] \cupdot \{a,c,f\}$: the reader can
easily check that each $\cupdot$ (resp., each $\minusdot$) is a valid
disjoint union (resp., subset complement), and that we have only used the
non-cancelling intersections. Note that this is not the only valid
expression, for instance we can also obtain the union with the expression
$[\{a,b,d\} \minusdot \{a,b\}] \cup [\{a,b,c,e\} \minusdot \{a,c\}] \cup
   \{a,c,f\}$.

**What we know:**
We have tried on millions of examples by a bruteforce approach and this always seems to be true. We have some partial results in [a note on arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/2401.16210) (calling this conjecture the “Non-Cancelling Intersections Conjecture”) concerning a reformulation of this conjecture, but we do not have a general solution so far.

Comment: I feel that there must be a way to formulate this using lattices... (And I see that you have "Möbius inversion" as a tag.)

Comment: MathJax note: The `$` that ends the "preamble" must appear immediately adjacent to the opening text of the post, or else the post itself will start with spurious blank space. TeX note: In `{align}` environments, even-numbered columns start with atoms, making $\begin{aligned}a&=b\end{aligned}$ `\begin{align} a & = b \end{align}` space nicely but requiring you to insert the atom yourself in $\begin{aligned}a=&b\end{aligned}$ `\begin{align} a = & b \end{align}`, making it $\begin{aligned}a={}&b\end{aligned}$ `\begin{align} a ={} & b \end{align}`, for proper spacing. I edited both accordingly.

Comment: @SamHopkins You could also click on the paper

Comment: @mathworker21 Touché. So I added tags for these.

Comment: Do you require each non-cancelling intersection present in the expression for $\cup_i S_i$ and only once? Does intersection $S_T$ have to be a part of disjoint union if $|T|$ is odd, and complemented otherwise?

Comment: I am not sure but KLaus Dohmen : Improved Bonferroni Inequalities via Abstract Tubes  might provide some tools.

Comment: If $S_1=\{a,b\}$, $S_2=\{a,c\}$, $ S_3=\{a,d\}$, then the only non-cancelling intersections are the $S_i$ themselves, and you cannot do anything with them using the operations at hand. Perhaps, you need to correct the definition of cancelling?

Comment: @Ilya Bogdanov In your case the intersection $\{a\}$ is also non cancelling, because it is equal to $S_1\cap S_2$, $S_1\cap S_3$, $S_2\cap S_3$ and also to $S_1\cap S_2\cap S_3\}$ so its coefficient is $3(-1)+1(+1)=-2$. More explanation in my entry explaining  the conjecture in the "Blog del Imus" https://institucional.us.es/blogimus/en/2024/03/still-hot-from-the-oven/

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: We do not require such a thing, the only requirement is to obtain an expression that, at the leaves (seing the expression as a tree with disjoint unions and subset complements as the internal nodes), uses only the non-cancelling intersections. But it is possible to show that if such an expression exists then there is one in which *all* the non-cancelling intersections occur, and with their multiplicity being given by the Mobius fonction (consequence of Lemma 4.4 and Proposition 4.7 of the note, if you are curious)

Comment: @SamHopkins: yes, the coefficients of the various intersections are given by the Mobiüs function of the corresponding "intersection lattice". I do not mention the Mobiús function in this post to simplify the presentation as it is not needed to explain the conjecture

Comment: @juan Perhaps, it is better to insert such explanations into the question, in order for the reader to learn that without reading all the comments.